# How to distinguish ZFS pool from mounts?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I'd like to zerofill all free space in partitions inside a FreeBSD virtual machine.

The virtual machine contains a 512K boot `freebsd-boot` type slice (hope I got the terminology right here), followed by a 2.0G `freebsd-swap` slice and a 254.0G `freebsd-zfs` slice.

```
# gpart show da0
=>       34  536870845  da0  GPT  (256G)
         34          6       - free -  (3.0K)
         40       1024    1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064        984       - free -  (492K)
       2048    4194304    2  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
    4196352  532672512    3  freebsd-zfs  (254G)
  536868864       2015       - free -  (1.0M)
```

It's the layout created by the FreeBSD 10.2 installer by default when picking the "root on ZFS" option.

In the past with UFS I'd simply use `mount -t ufs` to list all UFS labels and simply create a zero-filled file on these mounts until no space was left.

However, with ZFS I am not longer sure. Now I get:

```
# mount -t zfs
zroot/ROOT/default on / (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/tmp on /tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/home on /usr/home (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/ports on /usr/ports (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/src on /usr/src (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/audit on /var/audit (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/crash on /var/crash (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/log on /var/log (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/mail on /var/mail (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/tmp on /var/tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot on /zroot (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
```

which doesn't give me a clue other than the names, which as I understand are merely a convention (bad style to *rely* on conventions). And repeating the zero-fill operation on *each* of those datasets seems a bit silly.

Would it be sufficient then to find all ZFS pools (`zpool list -pH|cut -f 1`) and look for those in the list `mount -t zfs` gives me? I.e. ignoring datasets from that ZFS pool.

**In short,** would it be sufficient to fill the free space on the mount points listed by (using Bash, but likely also works with Zsh):

```
mount -t zfs|awk '$1 ~ /^'$(zpool list -pH|cut -f 1)'$/ {print $3}'
```

or does the fact that ZFS has those datasets change what part I need to zerofill before compacting the virtual machine's disk on the host side?

---

Output when listing the ZFS pools and the mounts:

```
# mount -t zfs
zroot/ROOT/default on / (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/tmp on /tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/home on /usr/home (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/ports on /usr/ports (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/src on /usr/src (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/audit on /var/audit (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/crash on /var/crash (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/log on /var/log (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/mail on /var/mail (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/tmp on /var/tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot on /zroot (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
# zpool list -pH
zroot   270582939648    1668632576      268914307072    -       0%      0       1.00x   ONLINE  -
```

Comment: one complication would be that each of those zfs filesystems may have different quotas or reservations - so zero-filling just one of the filesystems with a quota smaller than the total zpool won't zero-fill the entire disk.  check with `zfs get quota  -t filesystem`

Comment: @cas: but wouldn't the root dataset (`/zroot` in my above example) be a good candidate despite quotas in the child datasets? Of course if that has a quote all bets are off.

Comment: yep, should be ok unless it has a quota set.

Comment: Note that creating files with all-zeroes content won't necessarily write all zeroes to disk, because ZFS supports transparent compression. Check `zfs get compression zroot -r`. If it isn't `off` everywhere, then writing huge sequences of zeroes will actually write something else to storage.

Comment: It seems like so long as compression is off on any file system without a quota set that filling the available space with an all-zeros file should write all zeros all of the empty space.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking too complicated.

You just need to zero-fill each pool, not each filesystem! (The latter doesn't make a lot of sense in ZFS.)

So just iterate over all pools (via `zpool list`). For each pool, do the following:

- Create a new ZFS filesystem with disabled(!) compression
- Create a new file in that system filled with zeros
- Sync
- Destroy that ZFS filesystem

Note that the above algorithm works correctly even in the special case that you have some pool which doesn't contain any filesystem. (either no filesystem yet, or no filesystem anymore)

Answer (score 0):

`zpool list` will give you a list of the ZFS pools, and `zfs list` will give you a list of all the ZFS datasets.